# How to help type inference using C# classes in F#

Tags: c#, f#, type-inference

Using bouncy castle v.1.0.1 which is written in C# I'm having issues with type inference. The C# code has a lot of inheritance and interface usage.

```cs
// Definitions
public interface IParameters<out TAlg> where TAlg: Algorithm { ... }

public abstract class SignatureParameters<TParam, TAlg, DAlg> : Parameters<TAlg>, ISignatureParameters<TParam, TAlg, DAlg>
    where TParam : IParameters<TAlg>
    where TAlg : Algorithm
    where DAlg : DigestAlgorithm {}

// SignatureFactory interface 
public interface ISignatureFactoryService
{
   ISignatureFactory<A> CreateSignatureFactory<A>(A algorithmDetails) where A : IParameters<Algorithm>;
}

// SignatureFactory creation
public class SomeClass : ISignatureFactoryService
{
   public ISignatureFactory<A> CreateSignatureFactory<A>(A algorithmDetails) where A : IParameters<Algorithm>
   {
       ...
       return (ISignatureFactory<A>)new SignatureFactory<Fips.FipsEC.SignatureParameters>(algorithmDetails as Fips.FipsEC.SignatureParameters, new Fips.FipsEC.SignerProvider(algorithmDetails as Fips.FipsEC.SignatureParameters, privateKey));
   }
}
```

Now when I use the library from F# the compiler shows issues because it can not resolve/map `IParameters<Algorithm>` to `FipsEC.SignatureParameters`

```ml
// usage F#
let vKey = ... // is AsymmetricECPrivateKey
let signatureFactoryProvider = CryptoServicesRegistrar.CreateService(vKey, new SecureRandom())
let sigParams = FipsEC.Dsa.WithDigest(FipsShs.Sha256)
// sigParam will be of type FipsEC.SignatureParameters

let sigFactry = signatureFactoryProvider.CreateSignatureFactory(sigParams)
// error, FS0001: The type 'FipsEC.SignatureParameters' is not compatible with the type 'IParameters<Algorithm>'
```

`FipsEC.SignatureParameters` is defined as

```cs
public class SignatureParameters: SignatureParameters<SignatureParameters, FipsAlgorithm, FipsDigestAlgorithm>
{
    internal SignatureParameters(FipsAlgorithm algorithm, FipsDigestAlgorithm digestAlgorithm): base(algorithm, digestAlgorithm)
    {
    }

    internal override SignatureParameters CreateParameter(FipsAlgorithm algorithm, FipsDigestAlgorithm digestAlgorithm)
    {
        return new SignatureParameters (algorithm, digestAlgorithm);
    }
}
```

I tried to define the right type but obviously this is not doing anything

```ml
let sigParams =  IParameters<Algorithm> = FipsEC.Dsa.WithDigest(FipsShs.Sha256)   
// error FS0001: this expression was expected to have type 'IParameters<Algorithm>' but here has type 'FipsEC.SignatureParameters' which itself is again Parameters<TAlg>, ISignatureParameters<TParam, TAlg, DAlg> (see above), so it should work...
```

Question now is, how can I help the compiler? I have tried to cast it, but without luck.

Comment: Does `SignatureParameters` in fact implement `IParameters<Algorithm>`?

Comment: Yes it does. Among other interfaces

Comment: where is SignatureParameters? do u mean SignatureParameters<TParam, TAlg, DAlg>? (I don't think you do). I assume you can write the same code in C# and it does work? try explicitly typing the code you have written.

Comment: without seeing the code, my inclination is to believe the compiler.

Comment: I've updated the question with the definition of `SignatureParameters`. It's a lot of involved code, so I'm not sure if I can nail the question correctly. And: I _do_ believe the compiler - but I might give him a hint about the used polymorphism in C#

Comment: Your code doesn't have the definitions needed to be a reproduction. Try casting to IParameters explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit cast in F# (with exception for `obj`), so you have to either explicitly cast to interface, or to use flexible types:

**1. Explicit cast:**

- using `upcast` operator:

```
let sigParams : IParameters<Algorithm> = upcast FipsEC.Dsa.WithDigest(FipsShs.Sha256)
```

- using the safe cast (`:>`) operator:

```
let sigParams = FipsEC.Dsa.WithDigest(FipsShs.Sha256) :> IParameters<Algorithm>
```

**2. Flexible types (note the `#` sign before interface type):**

```
let sigParams : #IParameters<Algorithm> = FipsEC.Dsa.WithDigest(FipsShs.Sha256)
```

The second one is especially useful in function definitions:

```
let doSomethingWithParameters<'a> (params: #IParameters<'a>) = // some action here
// ...
// usage of the defined above function:
FipsEC.Dsa.WithDigest(FipsShs.Sha256)
|> doSomethingWithParameters
```